# views_slideshow without using Drupal CMS

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, drupal-views, slideshow

I'd like to use exactly the same slideshow script like http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow but without using Drupal itself. Do you think it is possible? Perhaps the script is based on other OpenSource project I don't know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of Javascript Slideshow plugins. Drupal's Views Slideshow module uses *jQuery Cycle* plugin. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of script that allow you to do some slideshow.

There are a lot of **[page](http://www.themeflash.com/30-powerful-jquery-slideshow-sliders-plugins-and-tutorials/)** that list lots of **[them](http://graphicalerts.com/20-best-jquery-slideshow-image-photo-gallery-plugins/).**

Isn't here something that is what you are looking for ?